# Proof KKT points are inside a ball and find the Lagrange multipliers

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier, karush-kuhn-tucker, regularization, global-optimization

I am trying to learn continuous optimization and I need to solve the following exercise. Despite the fact that I solved some exercises about KKT conditions and Lagrange multipliers, I can't solve this one. It seems to require an upper level of rigor and formalism. That's the exercise:

> Given matrix $ A \in  \mathbb R^{n \times  m}$ and vector $ b \in  \mathbb R^{m}$, Let $f$ be $$ f(x) := \|Ax +b \|_1^2 + \alpha \|x\|_1^2$$
>
> 1. Show that for every number $\alpha > 0$ function 
>      $f$ has exactly **one unconstrained global miniminum** at $x_\alpha$.
> 2. Moreover, show that each $x_\alpha$ is a KKT point for problem of minimizing $g(x) = \|Ax+b\|_1^2$ with $x$ in an Euclidean ball centered at zero with radius $\Delta_\alpha$.
> 3. Finally, show the associated Lagrange multipliers.

How do you solve these? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn´t it enough to ask for (i) only first?

Comment: @callculus, sorry, I thought the community would prefer to have it all at once.

Comment: Sure it is not bad to post the whole exercise. But to think that someone has a good mind to answer all three questions is very optimistic.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo,I think that is clearer now.

Comment: Which vector norm?

Comment: Absolute value norm. Considering your name, you must be Brazilian or Portuguese. Obrigado.

Comment: Do you mean the $1$-norm, i.e., the sum of the absolute values of the entries of the vector?

Comment: Yes, @RodrigodeAzevedo.

Comment: Are you sure? Squaring the $1$-norm looks strange.